# Question regarding a result about a homogeneous cubic equation $ C(x_1, ..., x_n) = 0 $ with integral coefficients

Tags: number-theory

I was reading "Analytic Methods for Diophantine equations and diophantine inequalities"
by Harold Davenport and I came across the result (in Chapter 13) that a homogeneous
cubic equation 
$$
C(x_1, ..., x_n) = 0,
$$
with integral coefficients, is soluble in integers $x_1, ..., x_n$
(not all $0$) if $n \geq 16.$

I got curious when I read this and I have two questions regarding it.

1. Has this result been improved to a smaller
   $n$ than $16$? I would appreciate a reference as I would be interested in
   reading the paper.
2. I was wondering if anyone could tell me if there is an analogous result in 
   $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$, a polynomial ring over a finite field. I just thought if there
   is an analogous result maybe $n$ will be smaller in this case 
   using some algebraic geometry, and I was curious to find out.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to Math Reviews? You could look up Davenport's paper to see whether any newer papers refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heath-Brown, Cubic forms in 14 variables, Invent. Math 170 (2007) 199-230, improves Davenport's result from 16 to 14. It appears the natural conjecture is that 10 will do.

I didn't find any improvements on Heath-Brown's result at Math Reviews.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!